# Why Does my Function that Writes to the File Keep Repeating Itself Then Timing Out?

Tags: c++

I am currently creating a Sudoku game with c++. I have most of the program completed except for one function that is giving me trouble. Here is the function below:

```
void writeGame(char board[][9])
{
   ofstream fout;
   char fileDestination[256];

   cout << "What file would you like to write your board to: ";
   cin >> fileDestination;

   fout.open(fileDestination);
   if (fout.fail())
   {
      cout << "Output unsuccessful.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Board written successfully\n";
   }

   for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
   {
      for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
      {
         fout << board[col][row];
      }
   }
   fout.close();
}
```

I also have a switch statement within another function with a specific case for this function:

```
void prompt(char board[][9])
{
   char option;
   cout << "> ";
   cin >> option;

   switch (option)
   {
      case 'Q':
         writeGame(board);
         break;
      default:
         cout << "Error";
         break;
   }
}
```

When the program prompts the user for the case, the writeGame function should run and output this:

```
> Q
What file would you like to write your board to: "file.txt"
Board written successfully
```

However, after it outputs that the board is written successfully, it repeats the function and outputs this:

```
> Q
What file would you like to write your board to: "file.txt"
Board written successfully
What file would you like to write your board to:
//exp: no output
//then the program times out
```

I call the prompt function within another function that display the board here:

```
void displayBoard(char board[][9])
{
   char option;
   cout << "   A B C D E F G H I\n";

   for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
   {
      cout << row + 1 << "  ";
      for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
      {
         if (board[col][row] == '0')
         {
            cout << " ";
         }
         else
         {
            cout << board[col][row];
         }
         if (col == 2 || col == 5)
         {
            cout << "|";
         }
         else if (col != 8)
         {
            cout << " ";
         }
      }

      if (row == 2 || row == 5)
      {
         cout << "\n   -----+-----+-----\n";
      }
      else
      {
         cout << endl;
      }
   }
   cout << endl;
   prompt(board);
}
```

I tried using a break within the for loop in my writeGame function but that had no effect, I thought the break in the switch statement would stop the function as well. I cannot seem to figure out how to prevent the function from repeating then timing out. Any tips are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: show the code where you are  calling prompt

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. As Waldson pointed out, the issue is likely elsewhere.